# malformed node or string on line 1 when I use ast.literal_eval using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, eval

I tried executing

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval('5+5')
```

Then I got `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x70e6bd2830>`.

So then I tried another:

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval(str(5+5))
```

And it evaluates it successfully:

```
10
```

But when I finally used it on an actual command `$math 5+5`

```py
@client.command()
async def math(ctx, expression):
    resp = ast.literal_eval(str(expression))
    await ctx.send(resp)
```

I still get the same error: `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x7d05357700>` for some reason. I'm using Python 3.10.5.
How can I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Whole code:**

```py
import discord, ast
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ""

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
prefix = client.command_prefix

def init():
    client.run(TOKEN, reconnect=False)

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    print('Connecting to server...')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
        print('Logged in as ' + str(client.user))
        print('Prefix: ' + str(prefix))

@client.command()
async def math(ctx, expression):
    resp = ast.literal_eval(str(expression))
    await ctx.send(resp)

init()
```

Comment: Can you print expression before evaluating and value of resp after `ast.literal_eval(expression)`?

Comment: yes i can, only gets an error when i use it as command

Comment: How you are running the command, Add that into the question.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I run it normally by `$math 5+5` @ParthS007

Comment: okay, Can u try with $math "5+5"

Comment: It still returns an error: `ValueError: malformed node or string`

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for explaining the question better

Comment: It is because the second call is evaluating a different string, `"10"`, not "5+5".

Comment: How though? Can you explain it further? @martineau

Comment: Because the `str(5+5)` becomes `str(10)`, since the addition happens *before* being passed to `str()` for conversion to the string `"10"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're no longer allowed to do addition in `literal_eval` since python 3.7.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904657/11107754)

I found some "safe expressions" to work with [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732605/11107754). Here's a simple demo:

```py
import ast

value = input()
co = ast.parse(value, mode='eval')

for node in ast.walk(co):
    if not isinstance(node, (ast.Expression, ast.Constant, ast.Add, ast.Sub, ast.Mult, ast.Div, ast.Mod, ast.Pow, ast.BinOp, ast.USub, ast.UAdd, ast.UnaryOp)):
        raise RuntimeError(f'Sorry! You gave an illegal syntax node: {node.__class__.__name__}')

print(eval(value))
```

This successfully evaluates valid math in python, such as `5 + 7*8 = 61` or `5 ** 7 = 78125`, and of course `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`.

Any bad operations that can potentially cause problems, such as `Call` or `Name` (meaning `variable_names_like_this` and `function()`) are not allowed. If you find any allowed operations that I missed, you can simply add them to the tuple inside the `isinstance` to allow them. You can precisely customize which syntax operations are allowed or not.

---

As a fair warning to anyone who is tempted to use `eval` without restricting the syntax you can use, this can execute regardless of your namespace fencing. It gets the `object` class, from which it gets a module to get `__builtins__`, after which getting `__import__` and doing bad things with that. For more danger, replace `'echo hi'` here with `'rm -rf /'`:

```py
[v for c,v in [c for c in ''.__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__.items() if c == '__import__'][0]('os').system('echo hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting appears to be because, [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, `None` and `Ellipsis`.

So when you do:

```
ast.literal_eval('5+5')
```

The problem is `+` which is a `BinOp` (which corresponds to the `<ast.BinOp object at 0x7d05357700>` part of the error message) and cannot be used.

However, when you do:

```
ast.literal_eval(str(5+5))
```

The order of evaluation is as follows:

```
ast.literal_eval(str(5+5)) -> ast.literal_eval(str(10)) -> ast.literal_eval('10')
```

Which no longer has `+` involved.